# Parsing JSON format from an HttpConnection

Tags: java, java-me, httpconnection

I am trying to read an API link which contains data of JSON format. this is what i am trying to read and display on the phone:

```
[[],{"index":"2","name":"jim","email":"jim@outlook.com","contact":"0122511336","username":"jim","password":"jim","photo":"student.jpg","status":"Active"}]
```

The program supposed to authenticate the username and password inputs and this dipsplay the content of the above from URL.

Below is the codes and so far what I have done. Please someone help me to get this through.

```
     package org.json.me;

    import java.io.*;
    import javax.microedition.io.*;
    import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
    import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
public class Login extends MIDlet implements CommandListener {

private String name;
private String email;
private int contact;
private String username;
private String password;
private String status;
private final String JSONformat = null;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name=name;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email=email;
}
public int getContact() {
    return contact;
}
public void setContact (int contact) {
    this.contact=contact;
}
public String getUsername () {
    return username;
}
public void setUsername (String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword (String Password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status=status;
}
public String toString() {
    return getName()+""+getEmail()+""+getContact()+""+getUsername()+""+getPassword()+""+getStatus();
}
public String fromJSON(String jsonString) {

    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        setName(json.getString("name"));
        setEmail(json.getString("email"));
        setContact(json.getInt("contact"));
        setUsername(json.getString("username"));
        setPassword(json.getString("password"));
        setStatus(json.getString("status"));
    }
     catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

    return JSONformat;
}    
TextField UserName = null;
TextField Password = null;
Form authForm, mainscreen;
TextBox t = null;
StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();

private Display myDisplay = null;
private Command okCommand = new Command("OK", Command.OK, 1);
private Command exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 2);
private Command backCommand = new Command("Back", Command.BACK, 2);
private Alert alert = null;

  public Login() {

myDisplay = Display.getDisplay(this);

UserName = new TextField("Username", "", 10, TextField.ANY);
Password = new TextField("Password", "", 10, TextField.ANY);
authForm = new Form("Identification");
mainscreen = new Form("Logging IN");
mainscreen.append("Logging in....");
mainscreen.addCommand(backCommand);
authForm.append(UserName);
authForm.append(Password);
authForm.addCommand(okCommand);
authForm.addCommand(exitCommand);
authForm.setCommandListener(this);
myDisplay.setCurrent(authForm);

}

 public void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
}

 public void pauseApp() {
}

 protected void destroyApp(boolean unconditional)
    throws MIDletStateChangeException {
}

 public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d) {

  if ((c == okCommand) && (d == authForm)) {
  if (UserName.getString().equals("") || Password.getString().equals("")) {
    alert = new Alert("Error", "You should enter Username and Password",    null,AlertType.ERROR);
  alert.setTimeout(Alert.FOREVER);
  myDisplay.setCurrent(alert);
    } 

  else {
        //myDisplay.setCurrent(mainscreen);
        login(UserName.getString(), Password.getString());
       }
   }
    if ((c == backCommand) && (d == mainscreen)) {
    myDisplay.setCurrent(authForm);
   }
   if ((c == exitCommand) && (d == authForm)) {
    notifyDestroyed();
    }
   }

     public void login(String UserName, String PassWord) {
      HttpConnection connection = null;
      DataInputStream in = null;
      String base = "http://sunday-tech.com/chunghua/api/login.php";
      String url = base + "?username=" + UserName + "&password=" + PassWord;

      OutputStream out = null;
try 
{
    connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
    connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
    connection.setRequestProperty("IF-Modified-Since", "2 Oct 2002                                     15:10:15 GMT");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-CA");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + (UserName.length() + PassWord.length()));
    connection.setRequestProperty("UserName", UserName);
    connection.setRequestProperty("PassWord", PassWord);
    out = connection.openDataOutputStream();
    out.flush();
    in = connection.openDataInputStream();
    int ch;
    while ((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
        b.append((char) ch);
        //System.out.println((char)ch);
    }
    mainscreen.append(fromJSON(b.toString()));
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.close();
    }
} 
catch (Exception x) {
}
myDisplay.setCurrent(mainscreen);

  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your setter methods to also change the TextField values. For example

```
public void setUsername (String username) {
  this.username = username;
  this.UserName.setString(username);
}
```

Comment: it still doesnt display the objects for me , it displays whole characters and i dont know what to do.... that output of the API is so confusing , should I make it JSONObject within JSONArray or how ? 

if someone just plz show me codes of how to get these object and append them i would be really damn happy :( it has been days and i am researching without getting it to work

Comment: Your fromJSON method should be extracting the information, right? Debug those lines to confirm